# SMART short offline test never ends for all drives of a RAID1

Tags: linux, mdadm, smart, smartctl

I'm having a strange situation here. After some three years in a low traffic server, one of two Samsung drives in a RAID1 has failed yesterday:

```
Personalities : [raid1]
md0 : active raid1 sdb1[2](F) sda1[0]
      732572608 blocks [2/1] [U_]
```

Since smartd hasn't reported anything, I checked the smart attributes and the only suspicious reading which differs on sdb (fail) compared to sda is:

```
sda:
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0022   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

sdb:
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0022   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       27650
```

G-sense error in a server rack? Maybe the sensor is failing?

But there's another funky reading on **both** drives: The latest short offline tests are "Interrupted (host reset)" and if I start a new one e.g. with `smartctl --test=short /dev/sda`, the selective self-test log shows:

```
SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
   1        0        0  Self_test_in_progress [90% left] (0-65535)
```

However, this short test never ends, even hours later the situation remains the same - on **both** drives. Could this be a firmware bug on the drives? Or is the controller failing?

Here's the full dump of both drives each with a short self test running:

/dev/sda:

```
smartctl 6.1 2013-03-16 r3800 [x86_64-linux-3.12.13-gentoo] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     SAMSUNG SpinPoint F3
Device Model:     SAMSUNG HD754JJ
Serial Number:    S281J9CZ500175
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0024e9 2026e8417
Firmware Version: 1AJ10001
User Capacity:    750,156,374,016 bytes [750 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 6
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s
Local Time is:    Fri Mar 21 09:04:35 2014 CET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      ( 249) Self-test routine in progress...
                    90% of test remaining.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:        ( 6540) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 109) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003f) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   100   100   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       59
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0026   055   052   000    Old_age   Always       -       6038
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0023   072   071   025    Pre-fail  Always       -       8729
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       10
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   252   252   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   252   252   051    Old_age   Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0024   252   252   015    Old_age   Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       23571
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   252   252   051    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       21
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0022   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0022   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   060   053   000    Old_age   Always       -       40 (Min/Max 20/48)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   252   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   252   252   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0036   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x002a   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       102119
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x0032   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
225 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       21

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Aborted by host               90%     23571         -
# 2  Short offline       Aborted by host               90%     23571         -
# 3  Short offline       Aborted by host               90%     23571         -
# 4  Short offline       Aborted by host               90%     23571         -
# 5  Short offline       Interrupted (host reset)      90%     23571         -
# 6  Short offline       Interrupted (host reset)      90%     23571         -
# 7  Short offline       Interrupted (host reset)      90%     23571         -
# 8  Short offline       Interrupted (host reset)      90%     23571         -
# 9  Extended offline    Interrupted (host reset)      90%     23571         -
#10  Short offline       Interrupted (host reset)      90%     23571         -
#11  Short offline       Interrupted (host reset)      90%     23571         -
#12  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     23559         -
#13  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     23535         -
#14  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     23511         -
#15  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%     23495         -
#16  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     23487         -
#17  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     23463         -
#18  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     23439         -
#19  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     23415         -
#20  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     23391         -
#21  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     23367         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 0
Note: revision number not 1 implies that no selective self-test has ever been run
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Self_test_in_progress [90% left] (0-65535)
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

/dev/sdb:

```
smartctl 6.1 2013-03-16 r3800 [x86_64-linux-3.12.13-gentoo] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     SAMSUNG SpinPoint F3
Device Model:     SAMSUNG HD754JJ
Serial Number:    S281J9CZ500174
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0024e9 2026e840e
Firmware Version: 1AJ10001
User Capacity:    750,156,374,016 bytes [750 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 6
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s
Local Time is:    Fri Mar 21 09:05:10 2014 CET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      ( 249) Self-test routine in progress...
                    90% of test remaining.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:        ( 6960) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 116) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003f) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   100   100   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       69
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0026   055   054   000    Old_age   Always       -       6442
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0023   071   071   025    Pre-fail  Always       -       8885
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       10
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   252   252   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   252   252   051    Old_age   Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0024   252   252   015    Old_age   Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       23571
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   252   252   051    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       21
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0022   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       27650
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0022   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   064   054   000    Old_age   Always       -       35 (Min/Max 20/46)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   252   252   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0036   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x002a   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       71575
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x0032   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
225 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       21

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Aborted by host               90%     23571         -
# 2  Short offline       Aborted by host               90%     23571         -
# 3  Short offline       Aborted by host               90%     23571         -
# 4  Short offline       Aborted by host               90%     23571         -
# 5  Extended offline    Interrupted (host reset)      90%     23571         -
# 6  Short offline       Interrupted (host reset)      90%     23571         -
# 7  Short offline       Interrupted (host reset)      90%     23571         -
# 8  Short offline       Interrupted (host reset)      90%     23571         -
# 9  Short offline       Interrupted (host reset)      90%     23571         -
#10  Short offline       Interrupted (host reset)      90%     23571         -
#11  Short offline       Interrupted (host reset)      90%     23571         -
#12  Short offline       Interrupted (host reset)      90%     23571         -
#13  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     23558         -
#14  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     23534         -
#15  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     23510         -
#16  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     23486         -
#17  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%     23471         -
#18  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     23462         -
#19  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     23438         -
#20  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     23414         -
#21  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     23390         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 0
Note: revision number not 1 implies that no selective self-test has ever been run
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Self_test_in_progress [90% left] (0-65535)
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Thanks for your hints!

Comment: Other explanations: http://superuser.com/questions/766943/smart-test-never-finishes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controller errors seem possible here.  Before you spend too much time on it, I'd suggest reseating all the cables.  It's possible something has come loose over time, and is causing problems.

Also, you mentioned smartd... did you disable this while trying to run the self tests?  It's possible this is interfering with the manual tests.

Was there anything in `dmesg` about why sdb is considered failed?  Both drives appear to be reporting their health as PASSED, and I don't believe mdadm actually uses any of the SMART data to determine the health of a drive.

Comment: Indeed, it collided with smartd. Thanks for the hint!